# how to build java me CDC app with ant? can i build using javaSE

Tags: ant, java-me, cdc

Hi im trying to build our java me app that works on CDC base, I have seen antenna, but cant get it to work, it seems to be geared towards CLDC, but i cant make it work, and am wondering if i need to do anything specific to make it compile a CDC app?
or if there is another way to build CDC apps with ant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need antenna feature, cdc app is like to JavaSe app.You could use plain ant for building cdc apps. JavaSE javac + cdc libraries is enought. 
F.e.

```
   <target name="app" >
        <mkdir dir="${dir.build.compiled}" />
        <javac  classpathref="app.cp"
                fork="true" debug="on"
                srcdir="<sources>"
                source="1.3"
                target="1.3"
                destdir="${dir.compiled}"/>
        <jar destfile="${app.jar}" basedir="${dir.compiled}" />
    </target>
```

Comment: this is best answer but the library i was using didnt fully work as it uses to many of the advanced features that android / me dont seem to have